# statsmodels ошибка импорта

Tags: python, statsmodels

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import MSTL
```

на двух компьютерах одна и та же ошибка:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'MSTL' from 'statsmodels.tsa.seasonal'.
```

Один компьютер Ubuntu 20.04, второй Windows10. На обоих системах актуальные обновления.

Comment: А таки какая у вас версия `statmodels`? Эта штука похоже в `0.14` появилась.

Comment: statsmodels==0.13.5

Comment: Ну вот. Или принудительно как-то ставьте `0.14` или не знаю. Пишут, что в `stable` релизе нет этого пока вроде как.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую, может есть чем заменить MSTL в statsmodels?

Comment: Я не знаю чем заменить. Попробуйте принудительно поставить `0.14` через `pip`, указав конкретную версию, либо вообще с `github` забрать и так поставить.

Comment: C:\Users\glukv>pip3 install statsmodels==0.14
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement statsmodels==0.14 (from versions: 0.4.0, 0.4.1, 0.4.3, 0.5.0rc1, 0.5.0, 0.6.0rc1, 0.6.0rc2, 0.6.0, 0.6.1, 0.8.0rc1, 0.8.0, 0.9.0rc1, 0.9.0, 0.10.0rc2, 0.10.0, 0.10.1, 0.10.2, 0.11.0rc1, 0.11.0rc2, 0.11.0, 0.11.1, 0.12.0rc0, 0.12.0, 0.12.1, 0.12.2, 0.13.0rc0, 0.13.0, 0.13.1, 0.13.2, 0.13.3, 0.13.4, 0.13.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for statsmodels==0.14